# Is it still possible to create an RSS feed from a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, rss

How do I create an RSS feed of a Facebook group? I see there's sites you can pay, but how do I go about doing it myself? Do they actually scrape the content, or does Facebook actually provide some way to get the information?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE September 14th 2018:** There is no public option to do that anymore. Only apps that get manually reviewed and approved by Facebook would be able to, and that effectively shuts down most if not all of them.

Comment: Both seem to be broken by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command-line utility called Tweeper to generate an RSS feed from a Facebook Group (as well as other sites, including Twitter (for which it was originally created) and Instagram.

Answer (score -3):

To get RSS from Facebook group

1. find the group. You'll notice the group is in the format https://www.facebook.com/groupname/ID/ where ID is some numbers.
2. copy the ID and paste it in the following link: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=ID&format=rss20

If there is no ID in the URI, just replace www with graph in the URI, and you'll find the ID in the JSON.

Comment: Well, that is the method for Facebook pages, not groups. :-(